# Format latest/newest post differently

Tags: posts, functions, customization

I need to apply different formatting to only the latest/newest post. I need the first post to be full size image and full post, all subsequent posts must be excerpts with thumbnails.

The code I am using only works on the first post per page so on the second page the first post is also full length full size image.

How can I have full post, full size image apply to the latest/newest post only?

```
    <?php 
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i == 1 ): ?>
    <!-- First Post -->
   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('homepage-content'); ?>>
    <div class="grid">
         <div class="grid__item one-whole">
         <header class="entry-header"> 
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php else : ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>   

        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta', get_post_format() ); ?><!-- entry-meta author and other info -->


    </header> <!-- end entry-header -->
     <div class="center-post-img">
        <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>  

     <div class="grid__item one-whole">


 <span class="post_desc"><?php the_content(); ?></span>

</div>
</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<?php else: // else $i == 1 ?>
    <!-- All Other Posts -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('homepage-content post-teaser'); ?>>
        <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid__item one-half palm-one-whole">

    <header class="entry-header"> 
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php else : ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>   

        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta', get_post_format() ); ?><!-- entry-meta author and other info -->


    </header> <!-- end entry-header -->
 <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>

</div><!-- 
     --><div class="grid__item one-half palm-one-whole">
     <div class="center-post-img">
        <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<?php endif; // endif for $i == 1 ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</article>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

include the conditional tag [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) within your if statement;

example:

```
if ( $i == 1 && !is_paged() ) :
```